# php oop implement simple __construct function

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am practising php from a tutorial but this tutorial is about php4 and mysql. I am running php5 and mysql functions require mysqli or PDO extension else I get the deprecated error and the script doesn't run.

The script below works fine

```
function connObj(){
    include_once("conf.php");
    $c = new mysqli(MYHOST, MYUSER, MYPASS, MYDB);

    if ($c->connect_errno){
        printf("Connect failed : %s", $c->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    return $c;
}
```

Instead I would like to implement the same thing using something like:

```
function __construct(){
    include_once("conf.php");
    $c = new mysqli(MYHOST, MYUSER, MYPASS, MYDB);

    if ($c->connect_errno){
        printf("Connect failed : %s", $c->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    return $c;
}
```

But later in the script I need this oop statement

```
$req = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);
```

But I get this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: req in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\tuto_php_poo_ex2\articlesManager_ex2.php on line 36
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
>   in C:\Apache24\htdocs\tuto_php_poo_ex2\articlesManager_ex2.php on line
>   36

Can someone show how to do have __construct() to work in this case?

-ooo-
The part of the code with the error you asked for

```
function showAllArticles($champs = null){

    if ($champs==null) {$champs = "*";}

    // connection à la bdd avec fonction
    $conn = $this->connObj();

    // memo requete
    $sql = "SELECT $champs FROM $this->table";

    // exec requete
    $req = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);

    // resultat dans le tableau assoc
    while ($data = $req->fetch_assoc()){
        $tableau[] = $data;
    }
    return $tableau;    
}
```

Comment: Stop reading PHP4 tutorials if you're working with PHP5

Comment: There is not much sense to learn about PHP OOP with a PHP4 tutorial because since PHP 5 this has been changed greatly. It's somehow sad to say, but you most likely have learned a lot of things that are more of historical use, instead start learning now again with a PHP5 tutorial.

Comment: @Mark, I think it's a good way to learn

Comment: BTW, THIS IS A PHP OOP TUTORIAL but it doesn't include mysqli statement but mysql changed since the time of this tutorial but this tutorial is a valid PHP OOP tutorial with classes and else

Comment: @bpascal123 - It might be a good way to learn how to do things the wrong way..... about on a par with reading Anglo-Saxon poetry being a good way to learn Japanese.... the use of `include_once("conf.php");` being a prime example of a bad way to do something

Comment: learning medieval English may help understand modern English. I am not implementing Java in php as far I know... I'll concentrate on include_once when I get further. Using it doesn't return errors or notice... Thanks

Comment: unfortunately, php5+mysqli online tutorials or printed books are not as available as php5+mysql. I'll stick with whatever resources I have. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not return value in class constructor, this is wrong:

```
function __construct(){
    include_once("conf.php");
    $c = new mysqli(MYHOST, MYUSER, MYPASS, MYDB);

    if ($c->connect_errno){
        printf("Connect failed : %s", $c->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    return $c;
}
```

You can do it like this:

```
class DB {
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $db;
    private $port;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $db, $port = 3306){
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->port = $port;
    }

    public function createConnection(){
        return new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->db, $this->port);
    }
}

$db = new DB('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'testdb');
$conn = $db->createConnection();
```

- Please, keep in mind that this is really very simple example.
- You might want to implement connection to database using [Singleton
  design pattern](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html).
- Including files in method like in your example is just wrong, you should pass values to method as method parameters.

Comment: Hi Yoda, using your answer which seems to be exactly what I need, I don't want to be a php expert... to understand your solution, I can't store connection variables into a separate file if I want to keep things simple?

Comment: Is port parameter required?

Comment: You can store your whole configuration in a separate file, it is common practice. If this simple example was a real application you would have 3 files: db.php - with DB class, config.php - with configuration, index.php - with the remaining logic. You can find it here: http://pastebin.com/G34ShYRP . Default port for MySQL database is 3306, therefore it is set as default value in the class constructor. The parameter is there in case that you would like to set some different port.

Comment: I'm upvoting, but please do not advise people to use the Singleton *anti* pattern. Also, in most cases, it would be better to just ask for the mysqli object in the constructor :)

Comment: All good to understand Yoda, now implementing it to work as expected will be another task. thanks

Comment: @SecondRikudo I wouldn't be so strict regarding Singleton pattern, because there are use cases where usage of Singleton pattern is beneficial. In case that author doesn't want to maintain connection to multiple databases (usage of Registry pattern might be useful in that case) then this might be one of them. It's more like suggestion for author to think about than advice.

Comment: @Yoda [Continue this, in chat we shall](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11).